# Error: Method rows of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user getting this error "Method rows of object worksheet failed". The code works fine on my machine. But the user got the error. I don't have easy access to the user's computer, so I am hoping someone can give me a guess as to this error.

```
Set wsB = wbB.Worksheets(1)
If Not wsB Is Nothing Then
    Dim EmpCount As Long
    EmpCount = wsB.Cells(wsB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<<Error here
End If
```

I've been combing through many webpages with this error and some of them point to unqualified references. But that's not a problem here. I couldn't find any other hint as to my specific problem.

I don't think there should be a version issue here but fyi: I have Excel 2007; user has Excel 2010.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this type of error if they have 2 excel workbooks open and the focus is on the other excel workbook but they're running code from the expected workbook.  Can you ask if they have more than one workbook open when they get the error?

Comment: Yes they have several workbooks open, but I've already tested this possibility and had no problems. I might explore this further to see if I can find anything. Thanks.

Comment: @sous2817 With three workbooks, I tried every combination of code workbook, active workbook and target workbook. None caused an error on my machine.

Comment: Today I've arranged a diagnostic session with the user; maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: good luck! The only other thing I can think of is how you're setting the wsB variable.  If possible, it may be worth explicitly setting the sheet reference w/ the actual sheet name just to make sure everyone is working with the same references.

Comment: @sous2817 Thanks for the ideas but a worksheet is a worksheet; it doesn't matter how I got to it. I'll post back after the diagnostic session to let you know how it went.

Comment: It depends on the situation...The way you are setting your sheet is by position of the worksheet tab order within a workbook.  If the user having an issue has changed the worksheet order, they're setting a different sheet reference.  You can test if with some simple code if you'd like.

Comment: @sous2817 I should have mentioned that that line was set that way for testing only. The actual code for setting the sheet is different but I'm certain that's not relevant. But the line with the error is exactly as it was in the production code.

Comment: well I'm stumped.  If you get it sorted, please post the solution.  Good luck!

Comment: @sous2817 See my answer for why the code wasn't working. It also explains why the question wasn't answerable.

Comment: @AlexBell just in case you're wondering: I figured out the problem. You weren't so far off the mark after all. I did have a problem with my worksheet variable. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! [red faced] I finally figured it out.

My code in the question left out a lot of things; my actual code looked more like this:

```
Dim wbB As Workbook
Dim wsB As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 10

    If needOpen Then
        Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(i))
        Set wsB = wbB.Worksheets(1)
    End If

    If Not wsB Is Nothing Then
        Dim EmpCount As Long
        EmpCount = wsB.Cells(wsB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<<Error here
        wbB.Close (False)
    End If

Next
```

Now you can spot the error. I failed to set the wsB to nothing so that even after the workbook was closed, the variable was not nothing. So it tried to count the rows on a non-existent worksheet.

Just adding this to the end of each loop will fix the problem:

```
Set wbB = Nothing
Set wsB = Nothing
```

So in conclusion, Rows.Count doesn't depend on whether the workbook/worksheet is active but it does need an actual worksheet with actual rows to count.